# JQuery is not working properly in my wordpress

Tags: javascript, ajax, wordpress

I have  button which pressed update row in database based on variable:

```
<input type="submit" id="wyslij" name="przycisk" value="<?php echo $checkboxstatus;?>">
```

and I try to make ajax connection in wordpress but its not working, i tried diffrent ways but still the same results. It's even not responding while clicking the button and not receving error.

Ajax:

```
    jQuery(document).ready( function() {
    
       jQuery("#wyslij").click( function(e) {
          e.preventDefault(); 
          checkboxstatus = <?php echo $checkboxstatus; ?>
          
    
          jQuery.ajax({
             type : "post",
             
             url : czekboks.php,
             data : {checkboxstatus},
            
          })   
    
       })
    
    })
    
    </script>
```

czekboks.php

```
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "obejrzaneodcinki";
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$query = " UPDATE uzytkownik
           SET status = '$checkboxstatus'
           WHERE id = '2115' ";
           
    if(mysqli_query($conn,$query))    
    {
    
    echo "good job";
    echo "<br />";
    }
```

Comment: Maybe use `fetch()` instead of jQuery ajax requests. Fetch is more modern and easier to use. Read about it here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API

Comment: I have 2 iq, can you help me with remaking this jquery to fetch()?

Comment: Not really. But I think I found an error: In the ajax you say `url : czekboks.php,`, but shouldn't it be `url: 'czekboks.php'`?

Comment: Yea, nvm i fixed it now. Sorry for trouble, and thank you.